# Laravel Eloquent BelongTo Model Access fails

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to get data by using Laravel Eloquent HasMany (reverse) relationship but I am not getting access. Whenever I try, it shows **Trying to get property 'name' of non-object**

I have two models. **Category** and **Article**. **Category** hasMany **Articles**. Here are the models:

*Category Model*

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id', 'name', 
]; 

public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Article');
}
```

*Article Model*

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id', 'headline', 'summary', 'body', 'status', 'cover_image', 'image_caption', 'image_credit', 'cover_video', 'video_caption', 'video_credit', 'category', 'meta', 'tags',
]; 

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category','category');
}
```

*Article Controller*

```
public function pendingposts()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $articles = Article::all();
return view('admin.article.pending-posts')->with(['user' => $user, 'articles' => $articles]);
}
```

*View Blade* (admin.article.pending-posts)

```
@foreach($articles->where('status', 'submitted')->sortByDesc('updated_at') as $article)
<tr>
<td >{{ $article->headline }}</td>
<td>{{ $article->category->name }} </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

here in blade, I can not access category through eloquent BelongsTo feature and I am not getting the reason behind getting the message:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>       Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\joliadmin\resources\views\admin\article\pending-posts.blade.php)

Comment: You should try with `with` e.g. `Article::with('category')->get()`, and another reason may be you not have any data for category

Comment: Do all your posts have categorys?

Comment: @kushal Suthar, I tried by writing same code as you mentioned and still getting same error.

Comment: Hi, I think your relationship may be wrong based on your file structure - try e.g. `return $this->hasMany('App\Article');` unless your models are in a model folder? Let me know if that's right and I can post as an answer for you :)

Comment: @swonder, yes, all articles/posts have a category.

Comment: @user10341554, no it is okay. other eloquent relationships are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
    public function pendingposts()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $articles = Article::with('category')
        ->where('status', 'submitted')
        ->sortByDesc('updated_at')
        ->get(); 

    return view('admin.article.pending-posts')->with(compact('user', 'articles'));
}

@foreach($articles as $article)
    <tr>
    <td>{{ $article->headline }}</td>
    <td>{{ $article->category->name }} </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**Updated Answer**

**Category Model**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id', 'name', 
]; 

public function article()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Article');
}
```

Comment: @MosharofZitu: Please check `Article` model in **Model** folder

Comment: @MosharofZitu do all your articles have categories

Comment: @MosharofZitu: And also display your `article` table migration file or check you have create relationship between 'article' table and 'category' table

Comment: @user10186369  it worked after changing 'category' column name into 'category_id' in article table.

Answer (score 0):

it worked after changing 'Article' tables 'category' column in 'category_id'. Thanks for helping.